# Can I allow anonymous access to AWS API Gateway documentation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a CloudFormation template that includes an API Gateway configured using an OpenAPI 3.0 body. I would like to make the OpenAPI specification available to the users of my API. Ideally within a nice GUI but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54209019) suggests that's not possible. I do not want to set up a developer portal.

My CFT contains a DocumentationVersion element that creates documentation for the API.

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-documenting-api-quick-start-publishing.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html) I should be able to download my documentation from a URL like

```
https://apigateway.[my_aws_region].amazonaws.com/restapis/[my_api_id]/stages/[my_api_stage]/exports/oas30
```

Indeed when I go to this URL I get something like

```
{"logref":"56f5173b-a329-11e9-a8d5-e97c525eb634","message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Which suggests that this will work with the correct token.

[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-documenting-api-content-provision-and-consumption.html) shows that you can control access to API documentation with a policy. (Although oddly it says that the account_id to use is the one of the users you want to grant access to - is that correct?)

So I tried adding the following resource to my CFT:

```
    "ApiDocumentationAccessPolicy": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
        "Properties": {
            "Description": "Read access to API documentation restricted by IP",
            "PolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "apigateway:GET"
                        ],
                        "Resource": {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                                "",
                                [
                                    "arn:aws:apigateway::",
                                    { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" },
                                    ":/restapis/",
                                    "*/documentation/*"
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "Condition" : {
                            "IpAddress": {
                                "aws:SourceIp": ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

However, I still get "Missing Authentication Token". I am confident that the "condition" part is correct as it is used elsewhere in CFT.

Is what I want to do possible, and if so where am I going wrong?

**EDIT** Adding `"Principal": "*"` to the policy statement above and also moving it directly to the APIGateway's policy don't appear to help either.